# My script is returning 0 even though the CSV source is not empty

Tags: autoit

I'm in the process of making a small program to tell me on the fly how many employees are currently punched in via AvayaCMS Reporting.

Right now, the way that it is setup is that I have an Avaya script to take a quick report and export it in a CSV that is used by my Autoit script.

In terms of debugging it, I feel like I missing something and need another set of eyes. 
launching the Staffing.au3 triggers the CSV script I'm using against the report. Even having the exact same data my message box still reports "0"

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <CSV.au3>
$i_AgentCount = AvayaData(@ScriptDir & '\Report.csv', @ScriptDir & '\Name List.csv')
MsgBox(0x40, "", $i_AgentCount)
Func AvayaData($s_ReportSource, $s_NameList)

$av_LiveData = _ParseCSV($s_ReportSource)
If @error Then Return -1

$av_NameList = _ParseCSV($s_NameList)
If @error Then Return -1

Local $i_AgentCount = 0

For $i_RowCnt = 1 To (UBound($av_LiveData, 1) - 1) Step +1

    For $i_AgtLst = 1 To (UBound($av_NameList) - 1) Step +1

        If StringStripWS($av_LiveData[$i_RowCnt][1], 3) = StringStripWS($av_NameList[$i_AgtLst][0], 3) Then

            $i_AgentCount += 1

        EndIf

    Next

Next

;Return the Agent Count
Return $i_AgentCount

EndFunc
```

Name List.csv

```
 Agent Name
"Doe, Jane"
"Doe, John"
```

Report.csv

```
,Agent Name,Login ID,Extn,AUX Reason,State,Split/Skill,Time,VDN Name
5,"Doe, John",5930001,1000001,7,AUXOUT,999,51:32:00,
2,"Doe, Jane",5930002,1000002,7,AUXOUT,999,52:32:00,
```

Comment: Do you want to check whether a Name of "Name List.csv" is in the other CSV? and what if it is found?

Comment: Correct, If a name is found in Name list and is also in the other report that would tell me that the names found are currently punched in. So for the number of people that match, I had it setup with a msgbox. With the example reports I posted it should return 2, but its not.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: Yes I did, the message box still resulted with "0", since the report and name list information matches for both John and Jane, it should show display 2

Comment: What the @Xenobiologist suggested is, add some debug lines and track the error. Its a small piece of code and it pretty easy to debug. Start from _ParseCSV result and end with checking like eg. ConsoleWrite(StringStripWS($av_LiveData[$i_RowCnt][1], 3) & "=" & StringStripWS($av_NameList[$i_AgtLst][0], 3) & @LF)
You need to learn how to debug.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is something wrong with your pathes or with the function which reads the files. My code shows a 2 when I run it. So, firstly check whether the files are found and if you can read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested! It **works well** with the files supplied (copied them and names them as in your script)

please note the followings

- _ParseCsv() has been rewritten add parameters like $Dchar as delimeter etc. (see script)
- Note how I locate the names in the file (you can easily add feature to extend search but it won't be becessary)
- msgboxes are for explanatory purposes; comment them out if not need them anymore
- array.au3 is not needed

and the code:

```
$i_AgentCount = AvayaData(@ScriptDir & '\Report.csv', @ScriptDir & '\Name List.csv')
MsgBox(0x40, "", $i_AgentCount)
Func AvayaData($s_ReportSource, $s_NameList)


 $av_LiveData = _ParseCSV($s_ReportSource,",","oops...",True)
 If @error Then Return -1

 $av_NameList = _ParseCSV($s_NameList,",","oops: 2",True)
 If @error Then Return -1

 MsgBox(0,default,"$av_NameList (Number of lines) -> " & $av_NameList[0][0])
 MsgBox(0,default,"$av_NameList (Number of data in each line) -> " & $av_NameList[0][1])

  MsgBox(0,default,"$av_LiveData (Number of lines) -> " & $av_LiveData[0][0])
 MsgBox(0,default,"$av_LiveData (Number of data in each line) -> " & $av_LiveData[0][1])

  Local $i_AgentCount = 0
for $i = 1 to $av_NameList[0][0] Step 1


For $j= 1 To $av_LiveData[0][0] Step 1

   ;we can have  names from $av_NameList as well from $av_LiveData but in Live Data 2nd abd 3rd values are the names
   MsgBox(0,default,$av_NameList[$i][1] & $av_NameList[$i][2] & " <------------> " & $av_LiveData[$j][2] & $av_LiveData[$j][3])

   ;~   let's compare them if matched with any of the liveData lines
  If StringCompare($av_NameList[$i][1] & $av_NameList[$i][2],$av_LiveData[$j][2] & $av_LiveData[$j][3]) == 0 Then 
     $i_AgentCount += 1
     MsgBox(0,default,"Match found: counter: " & $i_AgentCount)
   EndIf     
Next   
 Next   

;Return the Agent Count
Return $i_AgentCount

 EndFunc

 Func _ParseCSV($f,$Dchar,$error,$skip)

    Local $array[500][500]
    Local $line = ""

     $i = 0
    $file = FileOpen($f,0)
     If $file = -1 Then
   MsgBox(0, "Error", $error)
   Return False
    EndIf

   ;skip 1st line (since it is the header)
   If $skip Then $line = FileReadLine($file)

 While 1
 $i = $i + 1
Local $line = FileReadLine($file)
If @error = -1 Then ExitLoop
   ;skip 1st line
      $row_array = StringSplit($line,$Dchar)
      If $i == 1 Then $row_size = UBound($row_array) 
      If $row_size <> UBound($row_array) Then  MsgBox(0, "Error", "Row: " & $i & " has different size ")
      $row_size = UBound($row_array)
      $array = _arrayAdd_2d($array,$i,$row_array,$row_size)

WEnd
FileClose($file)
$array[0][0] = $i-1 ;stores number of lines
$array[0][1] = $row_size -1  ; stores number of data in a row (data corresponding to    index 0 is the number of data in a row actually that's way the -1)
Return $array

EndFunc
Func _arrayAdd_2d($array,$inwhich,$row_array,$row_size)
  For $i=1 To $row_size -1 Step 1
  $array[$inwhich][$i] = $row_array[$i]
 Next
Return $array
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#region    ;************ Includes ************
#include "csv.au3"
#include <Array.au3>
#endregion    ;************ Includes ************
$i_AgentCount = AvayaData(@ScriptDir & '\Report.csv', @ScriptDir & '\Name List.csv')
MsgBox(0x40, "", $i_AgentCount)

Func AvayaData($s_ReportSource, $s_NameList)
    Local $i_AgentCount = 0
    Local $s = FileRead($s_NameList)
    Local $loggedInNames = FileRead($s_ReportSource)

    $av_NameList = _ParseCSV($s_NameList)
    If @error Then Return -1
;~  _ArrayDisplay($av_NameList)

    ConsoleWrite($s & @CRLF)

    For $i = 1 To UBound($av_NameList) - 1
        ConsoleWrite($i & " " & $av_NameList[$i][0] & @CRLF)
        If StringInStr($s, $av_NameList[$i][0]) <> 0 Then
            $i_AgentCount += 1
        EndIf
    Next
    Return $i_AgentCount
EndFunc   ;==>AvayaData
```